# NPE when changing orientation in Android JUnit test

Tags: java, android, testing, junit, instrumentation

I am attempting to write a test that checks that selections are preserved when changing device orientation. The problem is that the `ListView` has no children after the change. Does anyone have any suggestions about what to do to fix this test?

```
public void testSelectionAfterSaveInstanceState() throws Throwable {
    Log.d(TAG, "testSelectionAfterSaveInstanceState()");

    ListView lv = ((ListActivity) this.activity).getListView();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int cardIndex = (int) (Math.random() * (lv.getChildCount() - 1) + 1);
        final CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) lv.getChildAt(
                cardIndex).findViewById(R.id.checkmark);

        if (!ctv.isChecked()) {
            indexes.add(cardIndex);

            this.runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Assert.assertTrue(ctv.performClick());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "change orientation");
    this.activity
            .setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    Log.d(TAG, "assertions");
    lv = ((ListActivity) this.activity).getListView();
    Log.d(TAG, "lv.getChildCount()=" + lv.getChildCount());             // 0
    for (int i = 0; i < indexes.size(); i++) {
        View row = lv.getChildAt(indexes.get(i));
        Log.d(TAG, "row=" + row);                                       // null
        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.checkmark);                          // NPE
        Assert.assertTrue(ctv.isChecked());
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "finished");
}
```

Due to popular demand, here is the exact stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at bbct.android.common.activity.test.BaseballCardListWithDataTest.testSelectionAfterSaveInstanceState(BaseballCardListWithDataTest.java:513)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Also, [here is the full listing](https://github.com/codeguru42/bbct/blob/android-tests/android/common/lib/src/bbct/android/common/activity/BaseballCardList.java) of the `ListActivity` being tested.

Comment: Looks like you know what you are doing so please forgive the stupid questions... Is your activity recreated on orientation change? Will you post the ListActivity you are testing this on?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie [Here](https://github.com/codeguru42/bbct/blob/android-tests/android/common/lib/src/bbct/android/common/activity/BaseballCardList.java) is a full listing of the `ListActivity`.

Comment: I didn't notice you overriding onConfigurationChanged() in your ListActivity so I am guessing the activity is destroyed when you request a new orientation.

Comment: Orientation change is not synchronous, it posts configuration change and activity relaunch messages to UI thread handler, to be handled later in the UI thread. Not sure how that would exactly explain the behavior though. Need some sleep now.

Comment: @laalto I've come to the conclusion that I am encountering a threading issue here. This seems to come up quite often in my test suite as some of the tests must use instrumentation not on the main UI thread. I think this test can be run completely on the UI thread to avoid the issue I see here.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie No, I do not override `onConfigurationChange()` nor use `android:configChanges` attribute for the activity.